# Avoid returning writable references

Tags: java

I have a submission to do for software development and my professor urges us to not use return statements, that return object references.

The task is about a to-do list application, and I wonder if there is any easy way to not implement the todo-list as a object with such writable return references.
I managed to do this but since I use JDBC its just writing my tasks to the DB and the re-loading it into my list from the DB, which for me sounds like the same as just writing it directly in the list.

I have the lecture again next Thursday and will ask then, but maybe some of you has a clue.
In my opinion its completely justifiable to return a reference to the list, especially since the application changes a lot in scenes and windows.

Edit: Code attached.

Since I have not yet implemented it here is how I would do it.

```
public class TaskList {
    private static ArrayList<Task> taskList = new ArrayList<>();

    public  ArrayList<Task> getTaskList() {
        return taskList;
    }
}
```

Then I can get my TaskList in the different scenes like the calendar or overview by simply using the getter and modify the list.

Currently I have this code like that:

```
public class Calendar {


    private ArrayList<Task> usersTasks = new ArrayList<>();
    
    //Bunch of methods to draw my calendar

    private createTask(){

            Task createdTask = new Task(title,content,prio,color,duedate,today);

            //write task in mySQL db
            DatabaseHandler databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler();
            databaseHandler.createTask(createdTask,user);
    }

    private getTasks(){

            usersTasks.clear();
            //new dbHandler to fetch as ResultSet and write in ArrayList userTasks

    }
}
```

I hope the snippets are explaining since I left a lot out. The example is for my calendar view.

So currently, when I create a task, I would write it in the DB, then clear my ArrayList and then re-fetch it.

Comment: attach some code please

Comment: Java is an OOP language, so from my point of view you cannot _not use return statements, that return object references_ unless you only use primitives. Maybe you can add additional details or clarification to your question.

Comment: You need to explain exactly (with code) which references the proffessor was talking about. Is it about not returning references to internal structures? If so, use protective copies. Is it about modifiability? If so, use references made with `Collections.unmodifiableList` etc. But you need to explain their admonition better.

Comment: Maybe you should return [immutable objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162665/immutable-class) when you get the data from the database?

Comment: Returning an immutable object, or a copy of an object, is considered a good practice to ensure encapsulation isn't violated when you are exposing, for example, a List through a getter method. Obviously, that copy will still be returned *as a reference*. There are many cases where returning the original, mutable object through a getter method is perfectly fine, though, and I would say that your professor is a bit overly dogmatic.

Comment: Added code. We have the evaluation-table our prof uses, and at the aspect clean code, he writes "no getters return writable references to members"

Comment: @Hannes You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33529415/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-add-elements-to-list-using-getter-method-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> no getters return writable references to members

Your professor is right.

Suppose you have a class `SoccerTeam` with a `List<Person> members` field with the team members in it, and a getter to get the team.

```
class SoccerTeam {
    private List<Person> members;

    public List<Person> getMembers() {
        return members;
    }
}
```

Now a caller wants so do something with all of the members, except the goalkeeper:

```
SoccerTeam team = ... // Get soccer team from somewhere
List<Person> members = team.getMembers();
members.remove(0); // Example where we agree that the goalkeeper is always element #0
doSomethingWithMembers(members);
```

Now the team lost its goalkeeper! A team with its members should not expose a *mutable* reference to the lists of members itself. We want to be able to provide a list with team members, without allowing some caller to modify the list of team members.

However,

> not use return statements, that return object references

is a little bit poorly worded, since this would allow you to use primitives (or `void`) only.

---

- A fix would be to return a fresh list with the members: a *defensive copy*:

  ```
  public List<Person> getPersons() {
      return new ArrayList<>(this.members);
  }
  ```

  Calling `remove()` on the list would not affect the `members` field of our team instance.
- Alternatively, you could make an *immutable* (or more accurately: *unmodifiable*) list of members during construction of the team. Then the getter could just return the list, because it is guaranteed that the caller cannot modify the list. Trying to do so would result in an `UnsupportedOperationException` to be thrown.

  ```
  public SoccerTeam(List<Person> members) {
      this.members = Collections.unmodifiableList(members);
  }

  public List<Person> getMembers() {
      return this.members;
  }
  ```
- A third option would be to return a `Stream` instead of a list. A `Stream` does not provide a way to modify the underlying source itself. (The elements contained in the source can, however.)

  ```
  public Stream<Person> members() {
      return this.members.stream();
  }
  ```

  This will postpone actual traversal until a *terminal operation* is called on the stream.

Comment: Your second solution is flawed, in that it doesn't allow the class itself to modify its team. It should probably have its own modifiable list, and wrap in the getter like the first solution.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Not necessarily "flawed", it was more or less an example of moving the creation of an immutable list to the constructor. But I admit that the very nature of a football team may not be the best example of something having an unmodifiable list as a field.

Comment: Thank you for your time :) Helped a lot